# Adding two data frames but retaining index order of first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I  have made two sample data frames, both have same columns names, (Buckets and Amounts) and for both data frames "Buckets" is the index.

df1 has more rows(complete set) and df2 has subset of rows.

when i add df2 into df1, the operation works perfectly but index locations move and are not in the same order of original df1's Buckets=['3M','6M','9M','1Y','2Y','3Y'].. they are like 1Y,2Y,3M etc ..how can i retain ds1 original index order after the add operation too?

```
Buckets=['3M','6M','9M','1Y','2Y','3Y']
Amount1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
Buckets2=['1Y','2Y','3Y']
Amount2=[4,5,6]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Buckets','Amount'])
df1.loc[:,'Amount']=Amount1
df1.loc[:,'Buckets']=Buckets
df1.set_index('Buckets',inplace=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Buckets','Amount'])
df2.loc[:,'Amount']=Amount2
df2.loc[:,'Buckets']=Buckets2
df2.set_index('Buckets',inplace=True)
df1=df1.add(df2,fill_value=0)
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice the old index back with `loc`:

```
df1.add(df2,fill_value=0).loc[df1.index]
```

output:

```
         Amount
Buckets        
3M          1.0
6M          2.0
9M          3.0
1Y          8.0
2Y         10.0
3Y         12.0
```

Answer (score 2):

[`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) will perform DataFrame alignment which involves a sort operation if the indexes are not already aligned. Can make `df2` [`reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) `df1` before or after adding:

```
df1 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).reindex_like(df1)
```

Or

```
df1 = df1.add(df2.reindex_like(df1), fill_value=0)
```

*Note `reindex_like` will align both columns and index, can use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) if just looking to align index:

```
df1 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).reindex(df1.index)
```

Or

```
df1 = df1.add(df2.reindex(df1.index), fill_value=0)
```

---

Alternatively can create a [`CategoricalDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html) from the `df1.index` for both indexes then the `sort` operation produces the correct order:

```
# Create CategoricalDtype
cat_dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(df1.index, ordered=True)
# Change index dtypes to categorical
df1.index = df1.index.astype(cat_dtype)
df2.index = df2.index.astype(cat_dtype)
# Add aligns correctly based on Categorical Ordering
df1 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

---

All options produce `df1`:

```
         Amount
Buckets        
3M          1.0
6M          2.0
9M          3.0
1Y          8.0
2Y         10.0
3Y         12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

While the earlier answers both work, I prefer the following for its syntax:

```
df1.update(df1 + df2)
```

This does not require any further sorting or reindexing, so it's easier to read than the other solutions.

The idea behind this is that df1 + df2 returns either the sum of the two data frames, or NaN for those where df2 contains no values. The update will overwrite the existing values in df1, but only in those instances where the sum is not NaN.